# Add new information between convolutional layers and dense layers

Tags: python, keras

I want to mix result of simple classifier with the results of convolutional network to get more sophisticated classifier and test it.

Right now, I'm using keras example for Inceptionv3 net

```
    base_model = InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', 
    input_shape=(200,200,3))
    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(1024, activation = 'relu')(x)
    predictions = Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

I want to add class obtained from other classifier to the result of the first `Dense` layer, but don't understand how to send it to model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a model with two branches.

```
input1 = Input(yourInputShape)
```

Follow the same line until the dense you want to change the results:

```
v3out = base_model(input1)
v3out =  GlobalAveragePooling2D()(v3out)
v3out = Dense(1024, activation = 'relu')(v3out)
```

Have a similar construction for the other classifier:

```
otherOut = other_model(input1)
otherOut = MoreLayers(....)(otherOut)
```

Now you can either sum them if they have the same shape, or concatenate them (append one to the end of the other)

```
#sum
joined = Add()([v3Out,otherOut])

#or concatenate
joined = Concatenate()([v3Out,otherOut])
```

Finish the model as normally:

```
predictions = Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(joined)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=predictions)
```